# ARM GCC inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I am trying the following :

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    unsigned int op1 = 10, op2 = 20;
    asm volatile ("uadd8 %0, %1, %2" :
                "=r" (result) :
                "r" (op1), "r" (op2) );

}
```

I want to compile this for Cortex A9 I am using arm GNU GCC toolchain.

But I keep getting this error:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc test_2.c

Assembler messages:

Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `uadd8 r4,r3,r2'
```

I tried by forcing to thumb mode by adding `.code 16` also but no luck .

What is the issue here ?

Comment: Can you post the gcc command-line too? The flags are relevant in this case.

Comment: @JanHudec : I tried -mthumb -mthumb-interwork  -march=armv7-a and -mcpu=cortex-a9

Comment: The questions can be edited here. Please, edit the information into the question itself. And mention gcc version too, please.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the output of `gcc -S` and see what code is actually reaching the assembler that it might be complaining about.

Comment: Could it be some path issue with multiple toolchains mixing? Like you run gcc from one toolchain, but assembler run is from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the default ARM architecture in your compiler does not implement that instruction. The `uadd8` is supported in Thumb mode for architectures ARMv6T2 and ARMv7 and in ARM mode for ARMv6 and ARMv7. Hence you need to pass the proper `-march=` option to `gcc`. For example:

```
 -march=armv6
 -march=armv6t2 -mthumb
 -march=armv7-a
 -march=armv7-a -marm
```

You can check what is the default (or set by options) architecture for the compilation with:

```
arm-elf-gcc -E -dM -x c /dev/null | grep ARM_ARCH
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the comment I tried with -march=armv7-a but I still get this error

Comment: What is the output of `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version`? Perhaps you'd need to upgrade your toolchain. E.g. Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.09-64) 4.7.2 works OK with those options.

Comment: Thanks man :) I was adding this march flag to assembler flags instead of gcc flags ..Thanks :)